# Angular Scope variables are not updated in Controller when changed in UI and vice versa

Tags: angularjs

I have below controller

```
angular.module("test")
        .controller("AnyCtrl", ["$scope", "$state","$timeout",  AnyCtrl]);

    function AnyCtrl($scope,$state,$timeout) {
        $scope.jumpOutNotes="test"; 
    }
```

and below is my view

```
<!-- start of  Jump out reason window  -->
<div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">

        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="jumpOutNotes">Notes</label>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <textarea class="form-control"
                              id="jumpOutNotes"
                              name="jumpOutNotes"
                              type="text"
                              rows="4"
                              cols="200"
                              placeholder="Notes"
                              ng-model="jumpOutNotes"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <button ng-click="saveJump(jumpOutNotes);" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Save Jump Out</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

When i call saveJump function, i re-initate the value of ng-model variable it is not reflected in ui and similarly i try to access this value in that function it shows me last value

```
$scope.saveJump= function(jumpOutNotes){                         
             alert($scope.jumpOutNotes+ " : "+jumpOutNotes);
             $scope.jumpOutNotes="";
         }
```

The value passed in function as argument is the latest value in view but the scope value in alert will always remain "test". Not sure what is causing this issue. I am using UI-Router for views.

Below is code for my stateprovider

```
angular.module("test").config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", "$locationProvider", "$provide",
            function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $provide) {

                $stateProvider

                    .state("serviceMain", {
                        url: "/main",
                        templateUrl: "../resources/app/service.html",
                        controller: "AnyCtrl"
                        })
                    });
```

Comment: what about ng-click="saveJump('{{jumpOutNotes}}');"

Comment: There's a typo in your controller declaration: $scope$state, I wonder how does this not cause an error. Or if you didn't copy-paste, I wonder if you're omitting any important details :)
You mention an other controller: through what mechanism are you sharing this data between the controllers? By default, a controller's scope will be detached of an other, so the change won't propagate.
  Also, you should switch over to console-based debugging instead of alert. If you want to capture the immediate state of a variable (which is arguably the only use of alert) then you can use, eg. angular.toJson()

Comment: It looks like your `<textarea>` has same value of `name` and `ng-model` attributes. Please [take a look](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.6/docs/api/ng/directive/input) at what `name` is used for in AngularJS. It most certainly should be (always) different from `ng-model`.

Comment: @hon2a No that is not a problem i tried removing it and changing it.

Comment: @YashpalSingla, 
1. On Initial page load, does your textarea contain "test"?
2. Would you mind adding your state from UI Router.

Comment: @MichaelLynch Yes it contains "test", i have also added state from UI Router